# Buiding a stack in a map

Tags: string, scala, stack, split, scala-2.8

I have a string that looks like this:

```
 "7-6-4-1"
```

or

```
 "7"
```

or

```
 ""
```

That is, a set of numbers separated by -. There may be zero or more numbers.

I want to return a stack with the numbers pushed on in that order (i.e. push 7 first and 1 ast, for the first example)

If I just wanted to return a list I could just go `str.split("-").map{_.toInt}` (although this doesn't work on the empty string)/

There's no toStack to convert to a Stack though. So currently, I have

```
  {
    val s = new Stack[Int]; 
    if (x.nonEmpty)
        x.split('-').foreach {
    y => s.push(y.toInt)
      }
   s
   }
```

Which works, but is pretty ugly. What am I missing?

EDIT: Thanks to all the responders, I learnt quite a bit from this discussion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Stack(x.split("-").map(_.toInt).reverse: _*)
```

The trick here is to pass the array you get from split into the `Stack` companion object builder.  By default the items go in in the same order as the array, so you have to reverse the array first.

Note the "treat this is a list, not as a single item" annotation, `: _*`.

---

Edit: if you don't want to catch the empty string case separately, like so (use the bottom one for mutable stacks, the top for immutable):

```
if (x.isEmpty) Stack() else Stack(x.split("-").map(_.toInt).reverse: _*)
if (x.isEmpty) Stack[Int]() else Stack(x.split("-").map(_.toInt).reverse: _*)
```

then you can filter out empty strings:

```
Stack(x.split("-").filterNot(_.isEmpty).map(_.toInt).reverse: _*)
```

which will also "helpfully" handle things like `7-9----2-2-4` for you (it will give `Stack(4,2,2,9,7)`).

If you want to handle even more dastardly formatting errors, you can

```
val guard = scala.util.control.Exception.catching[Int](classOf[NumberFormatException])
Stack(x.split("-").flatMap(x => guard.opt(x.toInt)).reverse: _*)
```

to return only those items that actually can be parsed.

Comment: Thanks. I still need the nonEmpty check for x?

Comment: @Paul yes, nonEmpty check is not there

Comment: `x => {Stack(x.split("-").collect{case x if x.nonEmpty => x.toInt}.reverse: _*)}` bit. seems to cover the nonEmpty case :)

Comment: Yep. Works in my use case. I couldn't work out how to create an return an empty Stack[Int] when checking the first x was empty (my Scala is stil at the "change things semi-randomly until it works" level, unfortunately, and I find the compiler errors for type problems opaque)

Comment: @Paul: It will check initial string for emptiness on every iteration, instead of doing it just once at the beginning.

Comment: The problem with `if (x.isEmpty) Stack() else Stack(x.split("-").map(_.toInt).reverse: _*)` is the type returned.It isn't `Stack[Int]` because of the `Stack()`. This causes errors in other methods which need it to be `Stack[Int]` (or at least, that's the only reason I can see for the compiler passing this method OK but givig errors elsewhere)

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347718/code-golf-towers-of-hanoi/4353239#4353239 to see the entire code

Comment: @Paul - The compiler does the right thing (at least with this line on its own or as a `def`); `Stack()` is initially guessed as type `Stack[Nothing]`, but when the other branch of the if comes back as `Stack[Int]`, the result of the whole expression is widened to `Stack[Int]`.

Comment: @Rex Kerr, I'm not sure it is. See the little example I just edited into the bottom of my question

Comment: @Paul - Oh, you're using a _mutable_ stack.  Sorry, I hadn't caught that.  In that case, yes, you need Stack[Int]().

Answer (score 3):

```
(Stack[Int]() /: (if(x.isEmpty) Array.empty else x.split("-")))(
                  (stack, value) => 
                      stack.push(value toInt))
```

Comment: Thanks. It's X that can be empty, not the string once split? and can you explain it a bit? :)

Comment: @Paul `foldLeft` is used to recursively populate a new empty stack with the values coming from splitting the string.

Answer (score 3):

Dont forget the ever handy `breakOut` which affords slightly better performance than `col: _*` (see [Daniel's excellent explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715681/scala-2-8-breakout))

Used here with Rex Kerr's `.filterNot(_.isEmpty)` solution:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.Stack
import scala.collection.breakOut

object StackFromString {

  def stackFromString(str: String): Stack[Int] =
    str.split("-").filterNot(_.isEmpty)
      .reverse.map(_.toInt)(breakOut)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(stackFromString("7-6-4-1"))
    println(stackFromString("7"))
    println(stackFromString(""))
  }
}
```

Will output:

```
Stack(1, 4, 6, 7)
Stack(7)
Stack()
```